# vlc media player hanging while playing rtsp video link

Tags: libvlc

When I am trying to play video using libvlc  dependancy - 
compile 'de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:3.0.0' but app freezes after getting below log:

W/VLC: [8aa14528] mediacodec decoder: Decoder stuck: invalidate all buffers

Can anybody have solution on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which video you are playing but you should debug like this:
1. This seems like the video packets you receive is not valid or corrupted so first try with different test cases and and different network

2. Try using latest vlc 3.0 which is highly stable
3. still getting problem then switched to ffmpeg and play using ffplay.
4. In case you still you have problem then share me the logs here will check and update